# extract column names in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, tidy

I have a data set:

```
N <- 10
dt <- data.table(jan = rnorm(N), feb=rnorm(N), mar =  rnorm(N), apr =  rnorm(N), may =  rnorm(N), jun =  rnorm(N), jul= rnorm(N), aug= rnorm(N),sep= rnorm(N), aug = rnorm(N), sep=  rnorm(N), oct= rnorm(N),nov= rnorm(N),dec= rnorm(N))
```

I want to extract column names like `c("jan", "feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec")`

Since I have other columns not listed here, so `colnames()` is not working here. Thanks!

Comment: use `names(dt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not working. I will assume that your data frame was created like this:

```
N <- 10
dt <- data.frame(jan = rnorm(N), feb=rnorm(N), mar =  rnorm(N), apr =  rnorm(N), may =  rnorm(N), jun =  rnorm(N), jul= rnorm(N), aug= rnorm(N),sep= rnorm(N), aug = rnorm(N), sep=  rnorm(N), oct= rnorm(N),nov= rnorm(N),dec= rnorm(N))
```

So, in order to subset the data frame for specific columns by name, you only need to do this:

```
dt2 <- dt[,c("jan", "feb", "mar")]
```